# div layout common minimum height

Tags: html, css, layout, height

I want my `div` layout to have a minimum height. There's left panel and content. I can set up same min height for each `div`, but when there's more stuff in content than in leftpanel, content will be higher while leftpanel will stay at minimum height. I want them to be at equal height all the time. I've created a div container that has minimum height and inside it there are content and leftpanel with `height` set to `100%`, but instead the layout is higher than screen, even with container min `height` as low as `200px`.

Here is the code:

```
<html><head>
<title>mysite</title>
<style>
body {width: 900px; text-align: center; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; background-color:#66FFFF;}
div.container { min-height: 200px; }
div.logo { height:146px; width:100%; background-image: url("http://localhost/cms/images/header.png");}
div.links{ height:30px; width:100%; background-color: #0066CC; }
div.leftpanel { width: 25%; float:left; height:100%; background: #85FF5C; }
div.content { width: 75%; height:100%; float: left; background: white; }


a { text-decoration: none; font-weight: bold; color: #000080; }
a:hover { color: #FFA500; }
div.news { margin-left: 20px; margin-right:20px; padding: 25px; }
div.newstitle { text-align: center; color: #FFA500; font-weight: bold; }
div.newscontent { text-align: justify; margin-left:0px; font-size: 12px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="logo"></div>
<div class="links">
<a href="http://localhost/cms//index.php">HOME</a>
</div>
<div class="container">
        <div class="leftpanel">Stuff</div>
        <div class="content">stuff</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue of equal heights for each column (divs). Look at this article http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/ they explain multiple solutions for doing this. But it is not just straight forward, unfortunately :(

Update 1

Like they also write in the article, then css flexbox (stretch) is a good solution to solve this issue, http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/, the only disadvantage is that is not supported in all browsers (http://caniuse.com/flexbox)

Comment: Not working in all browsers is a major disadvantage.

Comment: @Rob if your requirement is that it should, then yes. As far as i can see, then it looks like its mostly IE8,9 thats not supported - then you maybe can support a fallback for those

Comment: Thanks. That's an interesting article. For now I will just use same background color for container as for leftpanel and I will try not to exceed left panel min height.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add overflow property to div.content. This overflow property need to have value scroll

```
div.content { width: 75%; height:100%; float: left; background: white; overflow:scroll;}
```